# Using tidyverse/dplyr to reassign unobserved values using histogram of observed values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Eels have been sampled during electrofishing operations in the field. Most were measured (batch=S),
some were not (batch=L).
I would like to reassign those missing eels in the L batch using the nearest 10 mm value and the 
size structure observed in individual "S" measurements.

```
eel <- structure(list(op = c(529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 
            529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 
            529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 
            529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 
            529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 
            529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 
            529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 
            529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 
            529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 
            545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 
            545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 
            545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 
            545L, 545L), size = c(101L, 103L, 110L, 112L, 115L, 119L, 120L, 
            121L, 121L, 121L, 123L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 135L, 140L, 146L, 147L, 
            147L, 148L, 150L, 152L, 152L, 155L, 159L, 160L, 164L, 164L, 164L, 
            175L, 180L, 184L, 190L, 192L, 193L, 213L, 216L, 227L, 233L, 235L, 
            240L, 253L, 256L, 278L, 287L, 289L, 303L, 307L, 312L, 323L, 80L, 
            82L, 92L, 93L, 100L, 112L, 114L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 128L, 131L, 
            147L, 149L, 151L, 156L, 159L, 161L, 164L, 165L, 167L, 168L, 172L, 
            195L, 222L, 228L, 242L, 257L, 265L, 265L, 275L, 290L, 294L, 294L, 
            307L, 310L, 315L, 330L, 374L, 80L, 143L, 176L, 165L, 141L, 139L, 
            93L, 138L, 129L, 143L, 139L, 126L, 84L, 126L, 119L, 129L, 111L, 
            112L, 426L, 188L, 186L, 293L, 235L, 188L, 173L, 177L, 176L, 165L, 
            165L, 166L, 141L, 231L, 168L, 167L, 186L, 168L, 161L, 187L, 129L, 
            155L, 84L), batch = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "L", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
            "S", "S", "S", "S", "L"), number = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 0L, 133L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 67L)), .Names = c("op", 
        "size", "batch", "number"), row.names = 4:133, class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried to do it with tidyverse using histogram, I extract data from my size structure using 
the following function (which will make sure that all observed values fall within the range of breaks). I want the new size to be placed every 10 mm.

```
fn<-function(x) hist(x,
      breaks=seq(min(plyr::round_any(x, 10,f=floor)),plyr::round_any(max(x),10,f=ceiling),by=10),
      plot=FALSE)
```

Then I apply the following code

```
hist <- eel%>% 
    filter(batch=='S') %>%
    select (size,op) %>% 
    group_by(op)  %>%
    by_slice(~fn(.x$size))
```

Here I have an histogram in the .out column with `breaks` and `counts`, and using those I would like
to create new lines in my dataframe. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way, probably not the best, I've used the `browser` argument to make out the details. One of the hard part was that numbers reassigned need to be integer, when rounding the numbers issued from the percentage per class size, some counts are added or lost. So I had to reassign some eels randomly to the size structure. Do to machine tolerance, the argument  `sample(1:nrow(df),rr)` did not work and I had to round `rr`. Note that I tried to use function `map` and `map2` and didn't manage it, so any other simpler way would be quite welcome.

```
group_sample <-    
    eel%>%     
    filter(batch=='L')%>%
    select (op,number)


individual_sample <- 
    eel%>% 
    filter(batch=='S') %>%
    select (size,op)%>%
    group_by(op)  %>%   
    by_slice(~fn(.x$size)) %>%
    rename(hist=.out)

reassigned_sample<- inner_join(individual_sample,group_sample,by=c("op"))  %>%
    by_row(..f=function(this_row){
          #browser()
          # frequencies
          vec <-this_row["hist"][[1]][[1]]$counts/sum(this_row["hist"][[1]][[1]]$counts)*pull(this_row["number"])
          # numbers are rounded, but there is a problem with sum
          roundvec <- round(vec)
          sumvec <- sum(vec)
          sumroundvec <- sum(roundvec)
          # difference between rounded numbers and numbers
          rr <- sumroundvec-sumvec
          # creation du jeu de données ressemblant au tableau de départ (moins id première colonne)
          df <- data.frame("op"=pull(this_row["op"]),
              "size"=this_row["hist"][[1]][[1]]$mids-5,
              "batch"="SL",
              "number"=roundvec
             )  
          # remove lines with 0 number
          df<-df[df$number>0,]
          if (rr >0) {
            # randomly removing eels from some samples
            # round(rr) necessary otherwise might not be exact integer
            sss <- sample(1:nrow(df),round(rr))
            df[sss,"number"]<-df[sss,"number"]-1
            # randomly adding eels for some samples
          } else if (rr <0){            
            sss<-sample(1:nrow(df),round(-rr))
            df[sss,"number"]<-df[sss,"number"]+1
          } else {
            # do nothing
          }
          stopifnot(round(sum(df$number))==round(sumvec))
          return(df)          
        }) %>%
    rename(table=.out)

bind_rows(reassigned_sample$table)


op size batch number
1  529   80    SL      3
2  529   90    SL      4
3  529  100    SL      4
```